# CustomAuthenticationProvider not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm working with SpringMVC and Spring security, and I've set a CustomAuthenticationProvider. It's important for me to say that I'm working just with annotations, i have NO spring-security.xml, i say this cause in every tutorial i see they use it to set the authentication manager but doesn't fit with my project. So, what I did is simple I created a CustomAuthenticationProvider like following:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

private CustomAuthenticationProvider() {}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    Account user = accountRepository.findOneByEmail(authentication.getName());
    if(user!=null){
        if(passwordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), user.getPassword())){
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), grantedAuths);
        }else{
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials for user " + authentication.getName());
        }
    }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for " + authentication.getName());
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

Besides, I've modified SecurityConfig.java that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I've added
Also I modified the configure method to set the authProvider as most tutorials say to:

```
package ar.com.neex.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices;

import ar.com.neex.account.AccountService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("ar.com.neex")
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me-key", accountService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .eraseCredentials(true)
            .userDetailsService(accountService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin?logout")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .key("remember-me-key");
    }

    @Bean(name = "customAuthenticationProvider")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I start up my application i'm having an error, it's the following:

```
2017-03-22 01:28:01.399 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.accountService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ar.com.neex.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ar.com.neex.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ar.com.neex.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I've tried adding spring-security.xml and adding the filter in web.xml like I saw in the tutorials( even though i think i don't need that ), but it's not working neither.

Please if you have any ideas, i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
@Component("cAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{
 ....
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("ar.com.neex")
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cAuthenticationProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    ....
}
```